# Dealing with "incorrectly" formatted JSON from a service?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm looking through the Knockout tutorials, and in the JSON examples, it assumes that web services would return JSON like this (if it was an array of JSON objects):

```
[  { "id": 1}, { "id": 2}, { "id": 3} ]
```

How would I deal with a service that returns a differently structured JSON?

```
[ { "resource": { "id": 1} }, { "resource": { "id": 2} }, { "resource": { "id": 3 } } ]
```

I want the id names, not the resource names.

Thanks.

EDIT: I fixed the incorrect formatting on resource (per Matt).  The JSON is valid, just not in the format that the KO examples would expect.

Comment: The second example isn't even valid JSON. `resource` should be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Oops.  I fixed the code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just loop through your data and flatten it out (assuming your original is an array of JavaScript objects rather than JSON):

```
var original = JSON.parse([ { "resource": { "id": 1} }, { "resource": { "id": 2} }, { "resource": { "id": 3 } } ]);
var flattened = [];
for (var i=0; i < original.length; i++) {
    flattened.push(original[i].resource);
}
```

If you really need the output back as JSON again, you can use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Matt, I fixed my example.  It's an arrany of JSON objects.  But, I can loop through that and flatten it, as you said.  So now I can do something like var flattenedArray = ko.observableArray(flattened);